# Bluemix can not add a deploy stage

Tags: ibm-cloud, jazz

I just tried the trial version of Bluemix, and I tried to create an app with the Library for JAVA and coding with GIT.

I edited the code, comitted, pushed, and I clicked Build and Deploy. This page only has a "Build stage". I am getting an error when I try to add a "Deploy stage".

The error message is "There was a problem saving the stage"

How can I create the "Deploy stage"?
Thanks

Here is my step by step:

1. Sign up a 30 days trial account
2. Create an new app
3. Select Liberty for JAVA
4. Select coding with git
5. Edit Code
6. Commit and push
7. Click Build and Deploy (By default there have one Build Stage here only)
8. Configure Stage
9. Add job (Build type) in Build stage
10. Got the error message when I click save

*error message: There was a problem saving the stage

Comment: Please post the configurations you set for the Build stage

Comment: @JakePeyser  BUILD STAGE:  Input type: SCM repository, Branch: Master, Stage trigger: Auto, Builder type: simple

Comment: Hello did the following answers solve your issue?  If not can you post where you are getting stuck?

Answer (score 2):

Without knowing your configuration settings on both your build and deploy stages, it is hard to definitively say why you get that error message. However, a common reason for that message is not correctly configuring the default OOTB "Build stage" before adding the "Deploy stage".

Go to your "Build stage", click on the gear icon, and click 'Configure Stage'. Add a job of type "Build" and save the stage. Now, when you try to add a "Deploy stage", you should have the option of selecting an Input Type of 'Job Output', which lets you select the 'Build Stage' This means this new stage will attempt to deploy what was built in the previous step. Finish configuring the "Deploy stage" and this time saving the stage should work.

Comment: Oops, I got the error message "There was a problem saving the stage" when I add a job of type "Build".

Comment: @user3527571 please update your question and state more clearly what it is you are doing (configurations, stage, etc) that causes your issue

Answer (score 1):

You are not doing anything wrong and you should be able to save the stage.

There was a temporary issue with creating stages but it has now been resolved.

Comment: This is not an answer, you should have commented.

Answer (score 0):

Once you are on the "Build and Deploy" page click "Add Stage".

Click the "Jobs" tab.  Click "Add Job". Click "Deploy".

Choose your space and org and click "Save".

Answer (score 0):

One of the reasons you may get the error in saving the build stage is when your stage is not configured correctly, if you have chosen specific builder type like Ant, Grunt etc, ensure that the build archive directory or build output directory values are specified correctly or in the right format. 
I noticed this error when I specified the builder type as ant, and provided the archive directory a value -DARCHIVE_DIR=${ARCHIVE_DIR}, my build stage was failing the save. I then modified the build command to hold the archive directory value and then saved the stage , which went through fine.
My Build command looked as below

```
    #!/bin/bash
    ant -DARCHIVE_DIR=${ARCHIVE_DIR}
```